# Convert Sorted DataView to Typed DataTable

Tags: c#, dataview

i have a strong typed DataTable named Account wich i sorted on Account.FullName:

```
DataView dvAccount = new DataView(dtAccount)
dvAccount.Sort = "FullName desc";
```

The fullname is a  generated field from my DataSet after my query, based on first name, middle, last etc. This means that sorting by SQL query is not an option unfortunately.

First i tried to get the table like this:

```
dtAccount = dvAccount.Table()
```

But this gave me the original Table the Dataview was based on. So after reading online i found out that i should have used the `DataView.ToTable()` function instead of the `DataView.Table()` function:

```
dtAccount = dvAccount.ToTable() as dsAccount.AccountDataTable; // returns null
dtAccount = ((dsAccount.AccountDataTable) dvAccount.ToTable()); // gives Convertion to Typed Datatable Error
```

Now i get the problem that my Account Table is Strong typed. so searching online tells me that i could go with the `DataTable.Merge()` Function or `DataTable.ImportRow()` for each row but these are told to be a very heavy procedures because every row gets checked on the Type. what's the best practice solution to this situation?

Comment: Why don't you remove DataTable from DataSet and then add sorted DataTable to DataSet.

Comment: Hi Nikhil! Thanks for the quick reply. Can you provide an example or more detailed explanation to your tip? I'm using Asp.Net with a Dataset layer and a Business Layer (Multi-Tier setup), where the latter is the place where i want to do my sortings preferably since i re-use my datasets with the queries on multiple locations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same issue. I used this kind of solution.

```
        dtAccount = New dsAccount.AccountDataTable;
        dtAccount.Merge(dvAccount.ToTable());
```

This works fine for me.
Tell me if you have a better one.